# nginx and IIS - dealing with invalid hostname and SSL

Tags: iis, ssl, nginx, hostname

**Setup**

Client <=(HTTPS)=> Nginx load balancer <=(HTTPS)=> IIS 8

*(I know some people would ask why to use SSL between the nginx and the IIS, but this is not the topic of my question here.)*

**Error case**

A spamming/scanning client connects with SSL with an invalid hostname, e.g. the hostname specified by the client contains a star (*). This makes the IIS close the connection during the handshake and Nginx then takes this as the IIS being down.

When all IIS-servers are then down, the next request gets a "Bad gateway" from the nginx. This allows clients to falsely manipulate the nginx the think the IIS is down.

**How to fix?**

How would one fix this?

- Is it possible to deny requests in the nginx config with invalid
  hostnames based on looking at the characters?
- Or is it possible to make the IIS behave differently in these cases? The IIS already has a catch all ssl binding which just returns a 403 forbidden, but this is not hit in the explained case.
- Or do I have to list all allowed hostnames specifically in the nginx configuration?

Comment: Have you setup a default host as a catch all in case of no match? you can use 'map' to detect such hostnames with a single IF in your location block(s) to return a 403 so it never reaches iis.

Comment: Default website: YES - on the IIS, there is a default site getting all http and https requests not matching any other site - but in case the client has hostname *.mywebsite.com and uses SSL, then the IIS default site is not hit - instead  the nginx just reposrts, that the upstream (the IIS) closed connection during ssl handshake. Regarding the 'IF': Can you give an example? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```html
http {
    .....
    map $request_uri $blockit {
        default              0;
        ~*\*\.;              1;
    }
    .....
    server {
        .....
        location / {
            if ($blockit) { return 403; }
            .....
```

Comment: I think I need a little explanation with these. :) What does this regex match that you gave?

Comment: *. but of course you need to figure out how you make a regex that captures for your needs, a simple perl test script can aid in testing before moving it to nginx